# Upload image in two place at one time

Tags: php

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

In one shot, How to upload image in two place. one into  thumb folder another into actual image folder.

Note: Not an multifile  upload.

Comment: use move_uploaded_file two times

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: no, it should be done in one short.

Comment: like this if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $folder . '1.jpg')) {
    copy($folder . '1.jpg', $folder . '2.jpg');
    copy($folder . '1.jpg', $folder . '3.jpg');
}

Comment: But looking better and optimized and looking default factory class, like any flags anywhere

Comment: I presume your thumbnail will be a different size?  If so, after move_uploaded_file, try using imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecopyresized to create the thumbnail.

Comment: this method i know, but looking better and optimized one

Comment: yes i know that method, that will do two mirror at one upload

Comment: @Bharanikumar Then why the fridge not specify these things in the actual question instead of this commenting?

Comment: Buddy no man, you right in your ans. my questions is like how to make mirror at one shot. while upload file. please ignore my ignorance

Comment: you want to upload same image in two different folder at same time???

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file()` has moved to the file to your `$target_path` path. So, There is nothing in your temp , for second time you use `copy()`. command to upload it.

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
        if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$uploads_dir/$name)) {
            throw new Exception('Could not move file');
        }
        if (!copy($uploads_dir/$name, $target_path1)) {
            throw new Exception('Could not move 2nd file');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds good. this how currently am process my upload. thanks one again.